# UWP: file picker disappears after navigation

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a button for save in my log file page and when I click on that a file picker opens. the problem is this file picker get lost when I navigate to different pages in the app. 
so after navigation and coming back to log file page this file picker is lost.

```
<Button Margin="4,0,0,0" Width="140" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource AbbGrey-15}" Content="Save Log" Command="{Binding EventLogs.SaveControllerCommand}"/>
```

.

```
public ICommand SaveControllerCommand => new RelayCommand(Save, o => true);
```

.

```
private async void Save(object obj)
{
    if (ShowDialog == false)
    {
        ShowDialog = true;
        FileFolderPickerModalDialog pickerDlg = new FileFolderPickerModalDialog(cvm.Connection);
        CustomModalDialog dlg = new CustomModalDialog(pickerDlg);

        StatusBarVM.Instance.HideStatusBar();

        Apps.AppCore.BaseLayouts.RootPage rootPage = Window.Current.Content as Apps.AppCore.BaseLayouts.RootPage;
        var contentFrame = (rootPage.FindName("MainBodyContent") as ContentControl).Content as Frame;
        await dlg.ShowAsync(contentFrame);
        ShowDialog = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: It seemed that you're using the custom file picker class. Your code sample was incomplete. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: As noted, you appear to be using a custom file picker class. But if the dialog were truly modal, it would block navigation (because the main window would be disabled). This makes me think that the dialog is actually in the page. When you navigate away, the page is destroyed, and when you return, a new page is created. The new page doesn't have the dialog.